# Support for cython speedups using PyDev in Eclipse with Python 3.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse, pydev

I'm using a fresh install of the latest Eclipse, PyDev and Python 3.12. I get a warning `warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found` when debugging some Python code. (I've run the suggested command for `setup_pydevd_cython.py` but the warning persists.)

I traced the warning to the end of `pydevd_frame_eval_main.py` with the call to `pydev_log.show_compile_cython_command_line()`. I modified the file to print the `ImportError` and got the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_11.0.3.202310301107\pysrc\_pydevd_frame_eval\pydevd_frame_eval_cython_wrapper.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _pydevd_frame_eval_ext import pydevd_frame_evaluator as mod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_frame_eval_ext'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_11.0.3.202310301107\pysrc\_pydevd_frame_eval\pydevd_frame_eval_cython_wrapper.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydevd_frame_eval import pydevd_frame_evaluator as mod
ImportError: cannot import name 'pydevd_frame_evaluator' from '_pydevd_frame_eval' (C:\Users\Alex\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_11.0.3.202310301107\pysrc\_pydevd_frame_eval\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_11.0.3.202310301107\pysrc\_pydevd_frame_eval\pydevd_frame_eval_main.py", line 45, in <module>
    from _pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_eval_cython_wrapper import frame_eval_func, stop_frame_eval, dummy_trace_dispatch, clear_thread_local_info
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_11.0.3.202310301107\pysrc\_pydevd_frame_eval\pydevd_frame_eval_cython_wrapper.py", line 30, in <module>
    mod = __import__(check_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_evaluator_win32_312_64'

0.11s - warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"C:\Users\Alex\.virtualenvs\technical_analysis-8gQMC4g_\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Alex\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_11.0.3.202310301107\pysrc\setup_pydevd_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 7912)
```

I noticed no `_pydevd_frame_eval_ext` folder exists in the `pysrc` path. Also, the `_pydevd_frame_eval` folder has no `.pyd` file for Python 3.12 (it stops at 3.10).

How can I get cython speedups to work for my setup?

- Eclipse Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
- PyDev for Eclipse 11.0.3.202310301107
- Python v3.12
- OS Windows 10